# What is the meaning in Rails of the name parameter in add_index :sections, [:name, :page_id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to understand what is the meaning in rails of the :name parameter in the context of adding an index. Does it always have to be like this? If so this seems very redundant, so I figured I am missing something. **Rails 3.2.13**

```
add_index :sections, [:name, :page_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

This line adds a compound index to table `sections`, consisting of two columns, `name` and `page_id`.